# how to solve flutter null value issue in my code?

Tags: flutter, dart, null

I want to keep null as a default value for product id, as it'll be later auto-generated, but I can't due to the flutter null safety check.
this is the instance creation code where I want to keep id = null:

```
var _editedProduct = Product(
    id: null,
    title: '',
    price: 0,
    description: '',
    imageUrl: '',
  );
```

and here is the code for my Product.dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Product with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;
  bool isFavorite;

  Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.price,
    required this.imageUrl,
    this.isFavorite = false,
  });

  void toggleFavoriteStatus() {
    isFavorite = !isFavorite;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

A screenshot of the error

[image]

Comment: Your id must be `String?` which means it can accept a null value.

Comment: This solved my issue:                                _final String? productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String?;_

Answer (score 0):

While you like to have `id` default value as null, First you need to accept nullable data. For `final String id;` will be `final String? id;` the default value can be provided on constructor by removing `required` to act as optional. `id` will have `null` by default.

To use `id` you need to check if it is null or not.

If you are sure it contains data use `!` at the end like `id!`, or

provide a default value like `id??"default"`, or

`if(Product.id!=null){...}`

```dart
class Product with ChangeNotifier {
  final String? id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;
  bool isFavorite;

  Product({
    this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.price,
    required this.imageUrl,
    this.isFavorite = false,
  });
...
```

Learn more about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety)

Comment: This solved my issue:                                _final String? productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String?;_

Comment: You are doing the same as I described here, and navigation didn't include on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Following changes solved my issue:

1. changing `final String id;` to `final String? id;` in Product.dart
2. changing `final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;` to `final String? productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String?;`